# How can I add margin-top of the background of a div?

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-position

I have this [page](http://test.dac-proiect.ro/landing-page/index.html), in which I am displaying a video inside a box, and want my background image to have some "margin-top" so it's not displayed touching the edge of the box. I tried to add `background-position: 10%`, but it is not working.

Right now it looks like this:

[image]

And this is my code:

```css
.eu {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(images/BODY-VERDE.png);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.bg-image {
  position: relative;
}
.bg-image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  /* max-width: 1200px; */
  /* corresponds to max height of 450px */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container-video {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: url(images/BODY-VERDE.png);
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-image" style="width: 70%;margin: 0 auto;">

  <div class="eu">

    <div class="text-sus">
      <p>Set us perspiciatis</p>
      <p style="text-align: center;color: white;font-size: 16px;">unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore</p>
    </div>

    <div class="video">
      <img src="images/VIDEO.png" style="width:100%;height:auto;">
    </div>

  </div>

  <img src="images/CU-PRETURI.png">

</div>
```

I also tried adding `.bg-image img {margin-top:10%;}`, but then everything went down and I just want the background picture.

Comment: Could you give it a `padding-top: 10%` and `background-position: 0 10%` ?

Comment: Yes but nothing changes

Comment: `background-position: 0 10%;` should work. I would make sure that you're not canceling the effect out elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving both coordinates:

```
background-position: 0 50px;
```

In the following example, the bg image has a top margin of 50px

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-image: url('http://www.bestmanspeechestoasts.com/wp-content/themes/thesis/rotator/sample-4.jpg');
  background-position:  0 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```